# flutter blue plus library bluetooth communication lag with esp32 driver

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, serial-communication, data-transfer

i am connecting an application with esp32 driver using flutter blue plus library , and it works fine but after some long hours of time there is a lag in reading and writing characteristics to driver, after rebooting the driver lag issue is solved(but I can't reboot all the time when this lag comes), I need to find whats the reason behind the communication lag , is there any way to find this issue? please help. here I am posting the driver connection code,

```
 Future<bool> connect(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    Future<bool>? returnVal;
    try {
      await device.connect(autoConnect: false).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10),
          onTimeout: () async {
        isConnected = true;
        returnVal = Future.value(false);
      }).then((value) async {
        returnVal = Future.value(true);
        _connectedDevice = device;
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      returnVal = Future.value(false);
    }
```

after connection read & write some characteristics.

```
 Future<void> readData async {
    try {
      BluetoothService? DataService =
      BLEComm().getService(DeviceServiceUUIDs.DataService);
      if (null != DataService) {

        BluetoothCharacteristic? Characteristic =
        BLEComm().getCharacteristic(
            DeviceServiceUUIDs.Volition,
            patientDataService);
        List<int>? Response = await BLEComm()
            .readCharacteristic(Characteristic);
        double Data = DataConverter.convertUintListoDouble(
            Response ?? []);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```